# How to show the route in google maps of an origin and destination through latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I was looking in the google maps documentation for the option to generate a redirect link to google maps (from my system) with the origin and destination data through latitude and longitude

I found the [following example](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Space%20Needle%20Seattle%20Seattle%20WA&destination=Pike%20Place%20Market%20Seattle%20WA&travelmode=bicycling) to show the route from a location to obtained based on latitude and longitude, and a destination,

How can I generate the url so that from an application it shows a google map with the route from a place a to a place b only having the latitude and longitude of both places. ?

Comment: What programming language are you planning to use here?

Comment: I think the language is indifferent since I need to get the redirect link, but if it is a base, it will be javascript

Comment: I think you mean that you want a link that have latlng as a value in the origin and destination, instead of the address in the sample right?

Answer (score 0):

### Just use a `latitude` and `longitude` value for the `origin` and `destination` parameters instead of the Formatted Address

In the [Directions Section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#parameters) of the documentation, on the part where the parameters are explained, it specifically says this:

> `origin`: Defines the starting point from which to display directions.
> Defaults to most relevant starting location, such as device location,
> if available. If none, the resulting map may provide a blank form to
> allow a user to enter the origin. The value can be either a place
> name, address, or comma-separated **`latitude/longitude`**
> coordinates. A string should be URL-encoded, so an address such as
> "City Hall, New York, NY" should be converted to
> City+Hall%2C+New+York%2C+NY.
>
> `destination`: Defines the endpoint of the directions. If none, the
> resulting map may provide a blank form to allow the user to enter the
> destination. The value can be either a place name, address, or
> comma-separated **`latitude/longitude`** coordinates. A string should
> be URL-encoded, so an address such as "City Hall, New York, NY" should
> be converted to City+Hall%2C+New+York%2C+NY.

As you can see on the description, you can just use a `latitude` and `longitude` when generating a URL. It should look like this:

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=47.620514791346366,%20-122.34927359227758&destination=47.610252,%20-122.341392&travelmode=bicycling`

And it should work as expected: [image: sample request]

It is encouraged that you read through the documentation for better API knowledge. But with that said, I hope this still helps!